# Injecting ViewModelFactory in different activities

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using the well-known Dagger-ViewModelFactory pattern to be able to inject a factory for all the `ViewModel` in all the activities.

```
@ActivityScope
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        return creator.get() as T
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I inject the factory into an `Activity` Dagger fails because the providers of the objects for the `ViewModels` that I'm not going to use are not always accessible. They are not because the modules that contain the providers have not been added.

For example, I have a *LogIn* activity and a *SignUp* activity, and this is the way I add the subcomponents for them:

```
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        ViewModelModule::class,
        FirebaseModule::class,
        LogInModule::class,
        BindLogInModule::class
    ])
    @ActivityScope
    internal abstract fun loginActivityInjector(): LoginActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        ViewModelModule::class,
        FirebaseModule::class,
        SignUpModule::class,
        BindSignUpModule::class
    ])
    @ActivityScope
    internal abstract fun signUpActivityInjector(): SignUpActivity
```

Please notice that when I create the subcomponent for `SignUpActivity` I do not add the Module `LogInModule` because I do not need the bindings in that Module.
The result is that I get the error

> e: com.package.my.AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.package.my.login.domain.LogInAuthenticator cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
>                   ^
>     A binding with matching key exists in component: com.package.my.di.ActivityInjectorsModule_LoginActivityInjector$app_prodDebug.LoginActivitySubcomponent
>         com.package.my.login.domain.LogInAuthenticator is injected at
>             com.package.my.login.repository.LoginRepository(logInAuthenticator)
>         com.package.my.login.repository.LoginRepository is injected at
>             com.package.my.login.domain.LoginUseCase(loginRepository)
>         com.package.my.login.domain.LoginUseCase is injected at
>             com.package.my.login.presentation.LoginViewModel(loginUseCase)
>         com.package.my.login.presentation.LoginViewModel is injected at
>             com.package.my.di.ViewModelModule.provideLoginViewModel(viewModel)
>         java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> is injected at
>             com.package.my.di.ViewModelFactory(creators)
>         com.package.my.di.ViewModelFactory is injected at
>             com.package.my.di.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory$app_prodDebug(factory)
>         androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
>             com.package.my.login.ui.SignUpActivity.viewModelFactory
>         com.package.my.login.ui.SignUpActivity is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.package.my.di.AppComponent → com.package.my.di.ActivityInjectorsModule_SignUpActivityInjector$app_prodDebug.SignUpActivitySubcomponent]

This happens because `LogInAuthenticator` is provided by `LogInModule`.

Does this mean that the only solution is to add `LogInModule` even if I don't really need to create `GoogleSignInClient` in the `SignUpActivity`?

Comment: Please always include the full "stacktrace" of the error message and the code around it. I believe the issue arises due to adding the `LoginViewModel` to the SignUp Component. Usually you register the `ViewModelFactory` once (e.g. your AppComponent) then you add the viewmodel bindings to the components where you need them, so just the login vm to the login component, the sign up vm to the signup component, etc

Comment: @DavidMedenjak  I'm not adding the `LoginViewModel` to the SignUp subcomponent. If I do it then it works but I would prefer not to do it

Comment: I did not add the entire error because I think that the problem is clear. It is the solution that is not. Please also notice that I create the factory once too. The problem is that I need to add all the dependencies in all the subcomponents instead of just the necessary dependencies for each specific subcomponent.

Comment: I added now the entire error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared both of `@ContributesAndroidInjector` methods to be dependent on `ViewModelModule`. Inside `ViewModelModule` you have declared all of the `ViewModels` out there, which means, that at the point when Dagger wants to construct the dependency tree for `SignUpActivity` it will also require **you** to explicitly mention how `LoginViewModel` should be constructed. This happens, because Dagger needs to know how each of the dependency declared inside `ViewModelModule` should be constructed.

The solution for you case will be either include all of the modules in all of `@ContributesAndroidInjector` declarations (which is an ugly approach), **or**, alternatively, move the provider method of `SignUpViewModel` to `SignUpModule` and do not include `ViewModelModule` for `SignUpActivity` declaration.

Here's the setup that works for me.

First, I have created a `BaseActivityModule`, which all of feature modules should **include** in their dedicated `@Module` classes:

```
@Module
abstract class BaseActivityModule {
  @Binds abstract fun bindsViewModelFactory(factory: MyViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Then, assuming we have 2 features: *Foo* and *Bar*:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule {
  @PerActivity @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FooModule::class])
  abstract fun contributesFooActivity(): FooActivity

  @PerActivity @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [BarModule::class])
  abstract fun contributesBarActivity(): BarActivity
}
```

The implementation class of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` should be scoped with `@PerActivity` because the same instance of `ViewModelProvider.Factory` should be provided each time that dependency is needed to be injected in the scope of particular activity:

```
private typealias ViewModelProvidersMap = Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>

@PerActivity
class MyViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: ViewModelProvidersMap
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

  override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    var viewModelProvider = creators[modelClass]

    if (viewModelProvider == null) {
      val entries = creators.entries
      val mapEntry = entries.firstOrNull {
        modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
      } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class $modelClass")
      viewModelProvider = mapEntry.value
    }

    try {
      @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
      return viewModelProvider.get() as T
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't create ViewModel with specified class $modelClass", e)
    }
  }
}
```

Where `@PerActivity` is declared this way:

```
    @Scope
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    annotation class PerActivity
```

`FooModule` and `BarModule` are declared as such:

```
@Module(includes = [BaseActivityModule::class])
abstract class FooModule {
  @Binds @IntoMap @ViewModelKey(FooViewModel::class)
  abstract fun bindsFooViewModel(viewModel: FooViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Module(includes = [BaseActivityModule::class])
abstract class BarModule {
  @Binds @IntoMap @ViewModelKey(BarViewModel::class)
  abstract fun bindsBarViewModel(viewModel: BarViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Then we are including `ActivitiesModule` in the `AppComponent` as such:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
  AndroidInjectionModule::class,
  ActivitiesModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    ...
}
```

With this approach we've moved the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` creation one layer down: previously it was in the topmost `AppComponent` and now each of subcomponents will take care of creating the `ViewModelProvider.Factory`.

Comment: but I need to include the factory and to build the factory dagger would need to inject the map of all the creators of all the view models so there would be a dependency anyway

Comment: *all the ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why you need to add the LoginModule lies in your error log. The error log traces the dependencies as below:

**SignUpActivity** <--is injected at-- **ViewModelFactory** <--is injected at-- **LoginViewModel** <--is injected at-- **LoginUseCase** <--is injected at-- **LoginRepository** <--is injected at-- **LoginAuthenticator**

The map above shows that you need to add LoginModule because Dagger needs it to successfully inject your ViewModelFactory into your SignUpActivity.

**EDIT**

Move `SignUpViewModel` binding from your `ViewModelModule` and place it in your SignUpModule like below:

```
@Module(includes = [SignUpModule.BindsModule::class])
class SignUpModule {

    // your other provides methods

    @Module
    interface BindsModule{

        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(SignUpViewModel::class)
        fun signUpViewModel(signUpViewModel: SignUpViewModel): ViewModel
    }
}
```

Then add subcomponents this way. Notice `ViewModelModule` has been excluded

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        FirebaseModule::class,
        SignUpModule::class,
        BindSignUpModule::class
    ])
    @ActivityScope
    internal abstract fun signUpActivityInjector(): SignUpActivity
```

Comment: That's right but the question was how to avoid having SignUpActivity depends on LoginModule: I'm not actually using LoginModule in SignUpActivity

Comment: this is what @azizbekian has suggested as well. It does not work because the factory still tries to access all the ViewModels